# external qwerty keybord for programming by compact framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

we decided to design a keyboard(bluetooth or data cable) for using on a smartphone.
so, can we programming a smartphone by compact framework?is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "possible"?  If the device has Bluetooth and you have the capabilities of creating a bluetooth keyboard, then certainly it would work.

The "programming" part of the question needs clarification, though.  You program in Visual Studio on your desktop PC, then compile the app and deploy it to the device.  Obviously this can be done with a Bluetooth keyboard attached to the PC.  If you're asking "can I develop C# applications directly on the WinMo device by simply adding a Bluetooth keyboard" then the answer is "No.  You would need a compiler.  There was an [open-source one](http://pocketgcc.sourceforge.net/pcsharp/) back in the 1.0 days (hasn't been touched since '04), but I've seen nothing since."

Comment: i develop in visual stdio on my desktop PC.so are there any examples?

Comment: Examples of what, exactly?  Developing an application?  What does Bluetooth have to do with it?  You need more detail in the question.

Comment: i want to manufacture a bluetooth keybord for smartphones.but i dont know about compact framework software development for bluetooth keyboards.i want examples if are there.

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you create a Bluetooth keyboard and pair it with the device, then it will act like a keyboard, sending keys to the keyboard driver.  This has nothing to do with the COmpact Framework at all.  It's akin to asking how can you use the .NET Framework with a keyboard on your PC.  They have absolutely nothing to do with one another.  A CF app can use key data from the keyboard driver regardless of where that data came from - USB, Bluetooth, SIP, RDP or whatever.

Comment: i will create a bluetooth keyboard for a smartphone man no for pc. like below link this 
http://www.theunwired.net/?item=review-think-outside-stowaway-universal-bluetooth-keyboard-for-smartphone
for example,this product has a hardware driver.How can I write to the my keyboard device driver I will create?