# How can I write to the my keyboard device driver I will create?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, keyboard, bluetooth

I would like to build a Bluetooth keyboard for a smartphone [like this product](http://www.theunwired.net/?item=review-think-outside-stowaway-universal-bluetooth-keyboard-for-smartphone).

This product has a hardware driver. How can I write device driver for my keyboard.

Comment: You already asked this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594472/external-qwerty-keybord-for-programming-by-compact-framework

Comment: but you dont reply my question :)

Comment: Why is this tagged compact-framework?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to write a driver if the smart phone already supports bluetooth keyboards. If it does you just need your product to support the bluetooth HID protocol.

If the phone doesn't support bluetooth keyboards, it sounds like your question should be titled "How do I write a keyboard device driver for Windows Mobile?".

Comment: Which is what I said in the original.

Comment: there is not a bluetooth keyboard yet.i will create it.i want to become a bluetooth keyboard manufacturer for my smartphone.yes How do I write a keyboard(I WILL CREATE IT) device driver for Windows Mobile?